# World Maps in iOS

Tags: ios, graphics, dictionary, vector

There are plenty of good mapping libraries like default MapKit or Route-Me or MapBox. What I need is a mechanism, that will help me to display a world map with some graphics or text marks on it, but I don't need to go further than country view. The requirements are:

- List item
- free
- customizable (change color, texts)
- able to draw some element on country (draw(SomeCountry, SomeGraphics)
- able to highlight some part (highlight(SomeCountry))
- able to work offline (or load maps once)

I see two possible variants: 
- to find a lib, that will fit all this requirement (remember: level of details more than on courtiers level is redundant). In this case, could you please recommend such one?
- to use some vector image (SVG for example) and find a tool that will minimize effort to implement functionality mentioned above (draw over, highlight). Also, what lib could you recommend?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at WhirlyGlobe:

http://mousebird.github.com/WhirlyGlobe/

This IS the country level cool looking view you are looking for.

[image]